localhost на другом диске
Установил связку LAMPP. Ось - Mint 21.3. Хотел создать виртуальный хост на другом диске. Выполнял по схеме:

Создайте новую папку для нашего виртуального хоста:
$ sudo mkdir /media/medusa/ARHIVE_PROGRAMS/public_html/NAME
(NAME - название сайта)

Выставляем доступ:
$ sudo chown medusa:www-data -R /media/medusa/ARHIVE_PROGRAMS/public_html/NAME
$ sudo chmod -R 777 /media/medusa/ARHIVE_PROGRAMS/public_html/NAME

Теперь можно добавлять виртуальный хост, для этого создайте файл и наполните его содержимым:


sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/NAME.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName NAME
ServerAlias www.NAME
ServerAdmin medusa@localhost.loc

DocumentRoot /media/medusa/ARHIVE_PROGRAMS/public_html/NAME
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /media/medusa/ARHIVE_PROGRAMS/public_html/NAME>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog /media/medusa/ARHIVE_PROGRAMS/public_html/error.log
CustomLog /media/medusa/ARHIVE_PROGRAMS/public_html/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>


Нужно активировать наш хост:
$ sudo a2ensite NAME.conf
[$ sudo a2dissite NAME.conf]

Перезапускаем веб-сервер:
$ sudo systemctl restart apache2

Добавьте строчку в /etc/hosts:


$ sudo vim /etc/hosts
 
127.0.0.1      NAME


Откройте браузер и в адресной строке наберите NAME.

Получаю сообщение, что такого URL нет на localhost.
Расскажите пожалуйста, как настроить связку чтобы она видела мою директорию как localhost.  Уже третьи сутки рою Сеть, но Google выдает абсолютно не то, что мне необходимо.  Спасибо.
